# How to convert UIImage to NSData when the image's type is gif?

Tags: ios, uiimage, nsdata, gif

I've searched for so much articles about converting UIImage to NSData.There are some solutions.But when I only know the (UIImage*) image object , how could I configure it's NSData correctly especially when it's type is gif.

```
-(void)convertUIImageToNSData:(UIImage* )image{
    //if the image's type is gif,how to get it's data
    NSData *data = ?
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Gif is not supported in ios, it will treat the file as a normal file and also wont be store as UIImage without lib or something, you can just use `dataWithContentsOfFile` it to make it become `NSData`

Comment: Gif is supported in iOS. As we can see kUTTypeGIF in MobileCoreServices/UICoreTyoes.h

Comment: That doesnt mean `UIImage` and `UIImageView` support it, but sth like `UIWebView` and `WebKit` can

Answer (score 0):

Finally, I got the nsdata of an image by pass the original data when I just pick an picture from system album. That's little not so elegant.